# MongoDB OplogStartMissing

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, mongodb-replica-set

I understand that some times MongoDB secondary data becomes stale at which point, we need to perform an init sync from the Primary instance.

But sometimes we see error logs that look like this:

```
2022-07-22T21:24:20.065+0000 I  REPL  [rsBackgroundSync] Starting rollback due to OplogStartMissing: Our last optime fetched: { ts: Timestamp(1658512549, 30), t: 57 }. source's GTE: { ts: Timestamp(1658513748, 2), t: 88 }
```

How is the above error message different from:

```
2022-08-01T02:30:21.915+0000 I  REPL     [replication-0] We are too stale to use xyz as a sync source. Blacklisting this sync source because our last fetched timestamp: Timestamp(1659314292, 1) is before their earliest timestamp: Timestamp(1659320029, 301) for 1min until: 2022-08-01T02:31:21.915+0000
```

Comment: They are completely different. The first one is rolling back writes from one of the nodes, the second one says the oplog size is not sufficient for such long downtime. The question is not exactly a programming problem and would be more suitable for dba community really.

Comment: ok sure @AlexBlex, can you please help understand why it could be rolling back writes?

Comment: Sure, did you ask the question?

Comment: You mean in DBA forums?

Comment: Answered there https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315170/mongodb-oplogstart-missing/315174#315174